# how to install Nvidia GTX 750 ti drivers in ubuntu 14.04.4 32 bit system

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

guys!
I want to  install Nvidia GTX 750 ti drivers in ubuntu 14.04.4 32 bit system,but always not succeess!
first can't detect Nvidia geforce gtx 750ti

```
zjhxmjl@ubuntu:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)

zjhxmjl@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display:0 UNCLAIMED   
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fe400000-fe7fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:dc00(size=8)
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fe900000-fe9fffff
```

this is my system info:

```
zjhxmjl@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

zjhxmjl@ubuntu:~$ uname -r
4.2.0-27-generic
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers/680826

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind installing properietary drivers, I would always recommend to use the Nvidia precompiled binary drivers which can be found at http://www.nvidia.com/

You can also find some excellent info on using nvidia drivers on ubuntu at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: thanks,but why the system cannot know the video card?because old kernel ?or other reason?